# Python oneline switch

Tags: python

I am looking for a more elegant way to do the following:

```
py_loglevel = logging.DEBUG
if self.loglevel == "INFO":
   py_loglevel = logging.INFO
elif self.loglevel == "WARNING":
   py_loglevel = logging.WARNING
elif self.loglevel == "ERROR":
   py_loglevel = logging.ERROR
```

This works of couse, but it somehow annoys me because it is cluttering my code and is attracting my attention even though it is really trivial.
Can this be done in a oneliner?

Comment: Upvoted for your effort to write elegant code :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a dictionary:

```
levels = {
    'INFO': logging.INFO, 
    'WARNING': logging.WARNING,
    'ERROR': logging.ERROR,
}
py_loglevel = levels.get(self.loglevel, logging.DEBUG)
```

Alternatively, look up the name as an attribute on the module:

```
py_loglevel = getattr(logging, self.loglevel, logging.DEBUG)
```

provided the names match those defined on the module.

Comment: Ah, the simplicity... But you are stealing answers from @User.

Comment: @Marijn Pieters: Ok you where the first so you get my vote ;) Are you Dutch btw?

Answer (score 5):

```
py_loglevel = getattr(logging, self.loglevel)
```

Comment: Really elegant 'if names match'.

Answer (score 1):

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7872838/one-line-if-condition-assignment), a bad way is:

```
py_loglevel = logging.DEBUG
py_loglevel = (logging.INFO if self.loglevel == "INFO" else(logging.WARNING self.loglevel == "WARNING") else logging.ERROR)
print ":D"
```

Comment: Considered that but indeed to awful.