# One line if assignment in python

Tags: python, conditional-expressions

following this topic [One line if-condition-assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7872838/one-line-if-condition-assignment)

Is there a way to shorten the suggested statement there:

```
num1 = (20 if intvalue else 10)
```

in case that the assigned value is the same one in the condition?

this is how it looks now:

```
num1 = (intvalue if intvalue else 10)
```

`intvalue` appears twice. Is there a way to use `intvalue` just once and get the same statement? something more elegant?

Comment: It is scary that someBoolValue can have the value 10, instead of only True or False.

Comment: see edit, i meant integer value

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `or` here:

```
num1 = intvalue or 10
```

`or` *short-circuits*; if the first expression is true, that value is returned, otherwise the outcome of the second value is returned.

Comment: Be. Really. Careful. with the `or` short-circuits. Here there's no issue with it (because `someBoolValue` can only be True or False), but don't forget that some other objects like dict and list are considered as False when empty.

Comment: @FunkySayu: yes, but that same value is going to be considered false in a conditional expression *anyway*.

Comment: @John: yes, all objects in Python have a [truth value](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing), strings included. It doesn't matter what the value of the second expression is here.

Comment: Also, note that `0` is falsey, so `num1 = 0 or 10` will result in `num1 == 10`, even though `0` is an integer value. As @FunkySayu said, you should be _very_ careful using `or` like this.

Comment: @Frost: note that the conditional expression in the question used the *exact same test*: `intvalue if intvalue else 10`.

Comment: That's a good point. Thank you for pointing that out. So in that case, this will result in the same behavior. That makes me wonder whether that is the intended behavior of the code snippet or if `0` would be an acceptable value. That's another question though.