# What is this assignment? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, variable-assignment

I am copied from a book a genetic code and I found this assignment:

```
childGenes[index] = alternate \
    if newGene == childGenes[index] \
    else newGene
```

The full code is this:
main.py:

```
from population import *

while True:
    child = mutate(bestParent)
    childFitness = get_fitness(child)
    if bestFitness >= childFitness:
        continue
    print(str(child) + "\t" + str(get_fitness(child)))
    if childFitness >= len(bestParent):
        break
    bestFitness = childFitness
    bestParent = child
```

population.py:

```
import random

geneSet = " abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!.,1234567890-_=+!@#$%^&*():'[]\""
target = input()

def generate_parent(length):
    genes = []
    while len(genes) < length:
        sampleSize = min(length - len(genes), len(geneSet))
        genes.extend(random.sample(geneSet, sampleSize))
    parent = ""
    for i in genes:
        parent += i
    return parent

def get_fitness(guess):
    total = 0
    for i in range(len(target)):
        if target[i] == guess[i]:
            total = total + 1
    return total
    """
    return sum(1 for expected, actual in zip(target, guess)
        if expected == actual)
    """

def mutate(parent):
    index = random.randrange(0, len(parent))
    childGenes = list(parent)
    newGene, alternate = random.sample(geneSet, 2)
    childGenes[index] = alternate \
        if newGene == childGenes[index] \
        else newGene

    child = ""
    for i in childGenes:
        child += i

    return child

def display(guess):
    timeDiff = datetime.datetime.now() - startTime
    fitness = get_fitness(guess)
    print(str(guess) + "\t" + str(fitness) + "\t" + str(timeDiff))

random.seed()
bestParent = generate_parent(len(target))
bestFitness = get_fitness(bestParent)
print(bestParent)
```

The assignment is in population.py, in the mutate function. I have never seen this kind of variable assignment. What is this? What does the "\" symbol mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the alternative of:

```
if newGene == childGenes[index]:
    childGenes[index] = alternate
else:
    childGenes[index] = newGene
```

Answer (score 2):

The assignment has been split over multiple lines. The backslash [joins the lines](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#explicit-line-joining). The assignment can be rewritten as:

```
childGenes[index] = alternate if newGene == childGenes[index] else newGene
```

This is a [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) (sometimes called a "ternary operator") which is equivalent to:

```
if newGene == childGenes[index]:
    childGenes[index] = alternate
else:
    childGenes[index] = newGene
```

Answer (score 1):

It translates to:

```
if newGene == childGenes[index]:
   childGenes[index] = alternate
else:
   childGenes[index] = newGene
```

Answer (score 0):

The backslash here is a simple newline escape character. So the python interpreter reads those lines as one:

`childGenes[index] = alternate if newGene == childGenes[index] else newGene`

The one line conditional assigment was discussed amongst otheres here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7872838/one-line-if-condition-assignment