# inline if statement while multiple variable assginment

Tags: python

I know there are many resource such as [One line if-condition-assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7872838/one-line-if-condition-assignment/47724773)

but in my case I am assigning two variables from list with two items and want to know if there is a way of adding if statement in a line

my code is :

```
status, bytes = test_str[pos[1]+1:pos[2]-2].split()
if bytes == "-":
    bytes = 0
```

I want something like:

```
status, bytes if (bytes != "-" else 0) = test_str[pos[1]+1:pos[2]-2].split()
```

Comment: Your code is completely fine and more beautiful than any monstrous one-liner.

Comment: Nope, that is not going to work.

Comment: Why, why must it be on one line?

Comment: it doesn't I was just wondering if there is a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @KlausD.'s comment, but if you really have to, use:

```
status, bytes = [test_str[pos[1]+1:pos[2]-2].split(), (test_str[pos[1]+1:pos[2]-2].split()[0],0)][test_str[pos[1]+1:pos[2]-2].split()[1] == "-"]
```