# In Python, is it possible to assign an if-then statement to a variable?

Tags: python

I've defined a few variables below and I want to use them to define a variable.

```
today = datetime.today()
datem = str(datetime(today.year, today.month, 1))
curr_month = datem[5:7]
curr_year = datem[2:4]
list_early_fy = ['04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12']
```

I then want to use these to define the fiscal year I'm using.  I tried both methods below (the first one was what I was really looking for), but both just said "invalid syntax".

```
test_year = if curr_month in list_early_fy:
            print(int(curr_year)+1, curr_year)
    
def test_year:
        if curr_month in list_early_fy:
            print(int(curr_year)+1, curr_year)
```

Finally, I want to use that "test_year" variable in other places in my code.  Anyway, any suggestions on how to make this work?

Comment: What should be the `test year` equal to? Can you point with an example

Comment: It's not clear what value you want assigned to `test_year`. If you want a *function* named `test_year`, you are just missing the parentheses: `def test_year(): ...`.

Comment: Answer is No for your question. Refer this : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7872838/one-line-if-condition-assignment/47724773](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7872838/one-line-if-condition-assignment/47724773)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function needs to at least have parentheses, even if it takes no parameters, so `def test_year:` won't work. An `if` statement can't be assigned to a variable. Instead, you could define a function that accepts `curr_month` and `list_early_fy` as parameters,

```
def test_year(curr_month, curr_year, list_early_fy):
        if curr_month in list_early_fy:
            print(int(curr_year)+1, curr_year)
```

And you'd call it via `test_year(curr_month, curr_year, list_early_fy)`.

If you had a class that stored `curr_month`, `curr_year`, and `list_early_fy`, you could reference those class variables:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, curr_month, curr_year, list_early_fy):
        self.curr_month = curr_month
        self.curr_year = curr_year
        self.list_early_fy = list_early_fy
    
    def test_year():
        if self.curr_month in self.list_early_fy:
            print(int(self.curr_year)+1, self.curr_year)

c = MyClass(curr_month, curr_year, list_early_fy)
c.test_year()
```

Comment: Sorry if this is obvious; I'm still relatively new to Python.  I ran the first section of your solution and then tried to do:

`print(test_year(curr_month, curr_year, list_early_fy))`

This just gave a result of "None".  Is that expected?

Comment: @David yes, because `test_year` doesn't return anything. You could replace `print(int(curr_year)+1, curr_year)` with `return int(curr_year)+1, curr_year` in order for it to print the result via `print(test_year(curr_month, curr_year, list_early_fy))`.

Comment: I was still getting `None` when I replaced that piece, but that was really just important for testing.  So if I keep the `return` code in there, and use something like `this_yr = test_year(curr_month, curr_year, list_early_fy)`, then for instance, assigning a file name to be like `"FY" + str(this_yr)` should give FY21, correct?

Comment: @David no, because you're returning a tuple of `(int(curr_year)+1, curr_year)`, and a tuple's string representation is like `(item1, item2, ...)`. So the output will be `"FY(22, 21)"`. If you returned `curr_year`, then the output would be `"FY21"`. Passing multiple arguments to `print` works differently - `print(22, 21)` would print out `22 21`.

Comment: an if else _can_ be assigned to a variable, example : `if_func = lambda param: return param / 2 if param > 5 else return param * 2`, usage : `if_func(4)` gives 8, `if_func(6)` gives 3.

Answer (score 0):

The first piece of code is invalid because you're trying to assign a value while doing boolean. For the second, you forgot the () that would go after test_year to define the paramters. It should be `def test_year(curr_month):`. To use the function in your code, call it using `test_year(current_month_variable)`.

Answer (score 0):

First, you are not defining test_year, you are just printing cuur_year.
Then: Your second code will work if you add parenthese, like this:

```py
def test_year():
        if curr_month in list_early_fy:
            print(int(curr_year)+1, curr_year)
```

And one line if else based variable assignment (i guess this is what you wanted initially) works like this:

```py
num = int(input("enter number : "))
num = num * 2 if num < 5 else num / 2
print(num)
```

Above in normal syntax:

```py
num = int(input("enter number : "))
if num < 5:
    num = num * 2 # could be shortened to num *= 2
else:
    num = num / 2 # could be shortened to num /= 2
print(num)
```